# Is it possible to use json_populate_recordset in a subquery?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a json array with a couple of records, all of which have 3 fields lat, lon, v.

I would like to create a select subquery from this array to join with another query. The problem is that I cannot make the example in the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) work.

```
select * from json_populate_recordset(null::x, '[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4}]')
```

Should result in:

```
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
```

But I only get **ERROR: type "x" does not exist Position: 45**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to pass a composite type to `json_populate_recordset` whereas a column list is passed to `json_to_recordset`:

```
select *
from json_to_recordset('[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4}]') x (a int, b int)
;
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
```